# Querying list items that are vectors

Tags: r, list, reference

NB: Quite a beginner, so probably missing something obvious.

I am trying to write some generalizable code to do some factor-based analysis in R.  I have a list of factors and their levels such that

```
$group
[1] "NR" "NV" "NT"

$device
[1] "X" "Y" 

$width
[1] "fat" "nom"

$length
[1] "long" "nom"
```

I'm trying to write a loop to extract the individual levels of each factor in sequence (in the first case, "NR"), without using the name of the factor since that will change with different data sets.

I can get all the levels of a given factor by

```
factors[1]
```

or an individual level by

```
factors$group[1]
```

but how do I extract an individual level in a way that doesn't use the name of the factor? It can be done in a couple of steps, by for example

```
demo <- factors[[1]]
demo[1]
```

but that seems sloppy, since I don't actually need the variable demo to exist.  Is there a neater way?

Comment: You should rename your title to make this page useful to someone looking for help on how to query list items that are vectors, otherwise it just clutters search results.

Comment: good point, thanks! not using those terms may be why it took me so long to find the answer myself. . .

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out immediately after I asked the question, of course.  In case anybody else needs this, [[ and [ can be used simultaneously, so

```
factors[[1]][1]
```

gives

```
"NR"
```